# Google Analytics multiple tracking codes in one page

Tags: google-analytics

I have been playing a bit lately with research on Google Analytics because i need some clarity in a certain scenario and i can't really find any satisfactory answers.

I hate a certain website.
This very same website responds to www.site1.com and site2.com. On two separate Analytics accounts.

The person that started to handle this matter had put TWO separate snippets of analytics code on the home page.
So now on my analytics panel i have say, 100 visitors for site1.com and 120 visits for site2.com

My question is, am i to think that by this, this website is receiving 220 visits complexively?

The 2nd question is, if i chose to Redirect site1.com to site2.com, what would that mean for me on an Analytics level?

What i would in the near future like to do is merge data for both domains into one, whilst still keeping both of them , as i try to then fade out site1.com

I greatly appreciate if anyone would shed some light into this

Answer (score 3):

Google advises not to put 2 snippets on the same page. But you can put the new one on another page of the same website.